# Render meta tag from uncached plugin action

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I want to render a HTML meta tag (`<link rel="prev" href="..."/>`) from the fluid template of one of my uncached actions.

Using the [vhs-Viewhelper `v:page.header.link`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/Header/LinkViewHelper.html) does not work for uncached plugin actions, and I cannot make the action cached.

But I'd really like to render the tag from the fluid-template of that action, because that is the place where all the relevant information is present. I just need to render a partial to get the href. If doing this from other places, I'd probably have to re-implement much of my logic.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I think, this is not possible. Due to TYPO3 architecture, uncached plugins are inserted in a runtime into markers, like `<!--INT_hash-->`, which are stored in already cached version, meaning, that *header* is already rendered and cached. What you can try: is to hook into PageRenderer and add *link*-tag within a hook.

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi: Thanks - I suspected as much. Using a hook would not accomplish much, because then I'd have to render the URL in two different places, so I'd need all the parameters (about 10) in two places. Maybe it's possible to add another uncached plugin to the header area and let that plugin insert the link tags?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi: Could you make an answer from your comment?

Comment: @lorenz already gave a correct answer with solution, which I didn't know until now, so let's just keep my comment as comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same situation and using `<v:page.header` works for me in uncached context:

```
<v:page.header allowMoveToFooter="0">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{f:translate(key:'mobilizations.share.title')}" />
    <link rel="prev" href="{f:uri.page [...]}" />
</v:page.header>
```